# How to make some of the columns of the table to contain a dropdown box to filter the table?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, dropdown

I'm using VueJs and Vuetify. I have Vuetify's table where I present the data. I'm trying to edit the header column of some of the columns so I could add a dropdown search bar to filter the table. Something like:

[image]

Where `Select Item` is actually the header (please see the sort symbol aside of it). I could add it the dropdown above the table, like it's shown in the official docs, but I'm trying to make the dropdown as the header column itself and not just above the table.

The current code:

```
<v-data-table
  class="elevation-1"
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
  :items-per-page="tableItemsPerPage"
  :footer-props="tableFooterSettings"
  :loading="tableLoading"
  hide-default-footer
>
```

where `headers` is a simple array of the headers, for example:

```
{ text: 'data', value: 'pretty_data', align: 'center', sortable: true },
```

Of course I want the column to be still sortable (like it's shown in the image [the arrow]). How can I make it done?

Answer (score 1):

Created this working Demo. Hope it will work as per your expectation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    selected: [],
    headers: [
      {
        text: 'Name',
        align: 'left',
        value: 'name'
      }
    ],
    filters: {
      name: []
    },
    desserts: [
      {
        name: 'Frozen Yogurt'
      },
      {
        name: 'Ice cream sandwich'
      },
      {
        name: 'Eclair'
      },
      {
        name: 'Cupcake'
      },
      {
        name: 'Gingerbread'
      },
      {
        name: 'Jelly bean'
      },
      {
        name: 'Lollipop'
      },
      {
        name: 'Honeycomb'
      },
      {
        name: 'Donut'
      },
      {
        name: 'KitKat'
      }
    ]
  }),
  computed: {
    filteredDesserts() {
      return this.desserts.filter(d => {
        return Object.keys(this.filters).every(f => {
          return this.filters[f].length < 1 || this.filters[f].includes(d[f])
        })
      })
    }
  },

  methods: {
    columnValueList(val) {
      return this.desserts.map(d => d[val])
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.14/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.10/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.1.10/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      v-model="selected"
      :headers="headers"
      :items="filteredDesserts"
      item-key="name"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">
        <tr class="grey lighten-3">
          <th
            v-for="header in props.headers"
            :key="header.text"
          >
            <div v-if="filters.hasOwnProperty(header.value)">
              <v-select flat hide-details small multiple clearable :items="columnValueList(header.value)" v-model="filters[header.value]">
              </v-select>
            </div>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </template>
      <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ props.item.name }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much but I'm not sure why, everything inside the `<template slot="headers" slot-scope="props">` is not shown - It's being ignored for some reason (added `console.log` inside and outside of that html tag). I think it has something to do with `slot-scope="props"`?

Comment: That is defining the scope of the template. And in both the templates we are passing the data via slot. I hope you understand how slot works.

Comment: I do, it just weird. I copied the whole example just in case, and it still does not show the dropdown. It shows a regular table with the column, without the dropdown. I guess I'm missing something.

Comment: In the Vue docs, it says: `Deprecated in 2.6.0+. See here for the new, recommended syntax.` (regarding `slot`). Could it be it (I'm using `Vue 2.6.14`)? Source: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots-with-the-slot-Attribute

Comment: @vesii As per the official documentation - `The slot and slot-scope attributes will continue to be supported in all future 2.x releases, but are officially deprecated and will eventually be removed in Vue 3.`

Comment: I updated cdn link from `vue 3` to `vue 2.6.14` and it is working fine.

Comment: So what could be the reason not to present anything inside that template block? I added a console print inside of it (and before it) and it does not print it (only the one before it). I copied the whole example as-is.

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle as per your code and then i can look into that but its working fine here so i can not reproduce.